# What does binary plus operator do to int Array in C

Tags: c, dart, porting, code-conversion

I am porting an obscure library form C to dart.

a property is defined on a struct like this
`unsigned char   payload[256];`

I interpret that as an array of chars. So I converted it to
`List<int> payload;`

later in the original library there is this code

```
parser->handleDataValue( extendedCodeLevel, code, numBytes, parser->payload+i, parser->customData );
```

where 'i' is an index for a loop

I translated that to

```
parser.handleDataValue(extendedCodeLevel, code, numBytes, parser.payload + i, parser.customData);`
```

Now I am dealing with the error
`The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<int>'.`

I understand the dart side of the problem but I don't understand what the original C means to write its dart equivalent.

Comment: It performs pointer arithmetic. The other way to write it in C would be `&(parser->payload[i])`

Comment: For any array or pointer `p` and index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is exactly equal to `*(p + i)`. From this can be deduced that `p + i` is a pointer to the element at index `i` (i.e. `&p[i]`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ah, so does that mean that it is pointing to the next element in the `payload` array?

Comment: @xerotolerant: No. Adding 1 points to the next element. Adding `i` points to the element displaced `i` elements from the starting point.

Comment: Ohh, I get it now thank you.

Comment: @Lundin `List<int>` are basically collections in the dart programming language. I'm porting the library from C to Dart

Comment: @xerotolerant Fair enough :) Just making sure it wasn't yet another mistagged C++ post.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably translate `unsigned char payload[256];` in C to `Uint8List payload;` in Dart. That's an actual list of unsigned "char"s.

The pointer arithmetic can then be emulated by
`Uint8List.sublistView(parser.payload, i)`, which creates a view of the data of `payload` starting from the `i`th value, without copying, just like the C code.

Q.v. [Uint8List.sublistView](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-typed_data/Uint8List/Uint8List.sublistView.html).

Comment: Than you. that's exactly what the code was doing. In ended up with a much hacker solution but I'll change to this as It makes the most. sense